# The singleton set of a diverging sum

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology

I am wondering whether the singleton set containing a diverging infinite sum is open or closed. For instance is the following set open or closed (or both or neither) in $\mathbb{R}$:

{$\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{1}{n}$}

I'm thinking that it's both open and closed since the sum diverges so it doesn't actually exist. But at the same time, it feels strange to say that the set is empty, {$\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{1}{n}$} = $\emptyset$.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: Would this set be something like {$\infty$} instead? How do I classify {$\infty$} then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} $ is simply a notation. When we say it diverges, we mean that we can't associate any real number with this series (as per our defined rules of summation of series). Hence , if you consider $\{ \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} \}$ as subset of $\mathbb{R}$, then this is the null set, hence both open and closed in $\mathbb{R}$.

If you allow $+\infty$ to be the sum, then it wouuld make sense if you consider $\{ \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} \} ( = \{ +\infty \} )$ as subset of the extended real line, i.e., $\mathbb{R} \cup \{ -\infty, +\infty \}$. Then in standard topology over extended reals, the set $\{ +\infty \}$ is closed.

Comment: That was very helpful, thank you!